# How to make a download AUDIO with VueJS / Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, download

Currently I need to download all kinds of files... I have already made it possible to download PDFs, DOCX files, Images, among others. But when I try to download an audio file through BUCKET or other means, instead of downloading it, it opens the link to stream/play it.

This is my function

```
downloadFile(key) {
 this.axios
 .get('/files/download/'+key)
 .then(({ data }) => { 
   window.open(data.url, '_self')
  })
},
```

I've already tried other ways to create a fictitious element like the  by creating a "download" type attribute and associating a CLICK to it but it does the same thing, it opens a window for me to stream and what I need is for it to do a direct download.

This is my other example that I tried

```
downloadPdf() {
      this.axios.get(`files/download/${this.body.pdf.key}`).then(response => {
        let url = response.data.url;
        let link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
        link.click();
      });
    }
```